# Java-like libraries/frameworks for JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, oop, frameworks

I like the way Java works, in particular, implicit scoping of the `this` keyword (an absolute pet hate of JavaScript), namespaces, non-prototypal inheritance, and just about every feature JavaScript doesn't have.

Are there any frameworks which relieve the need for lengthy, statements like `Function.prototype.x.call`, `function.bind`, `var that = this;`, even if it just implements them but hides it. Preferably something which can integrate with jQuery for its thorough cross-browser, rubust abstracted interface. Something that allows writing in the style of mainstream OOP.

Comment: Something like [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/) might be useful to you.  Also, JavaScript is not a bad language by any stretch; it has bad parts, but it also has [really good parts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook).  Don't use the bad parts.

Comment: You may want to avoid bashing JavaScript if you want JavaScript help

Comment: Hey, if you're going to mark negative ratings, at least explain the error in my thinking. I'd like to see sensible comments supporting javascript. I suspect they're hard to come up with.

Comment: @Jodes: I don't think there's error in your thinking to the extent that you're giving your opinion. But your question reads more like a rant than anything. That said, Microsoft has a new endeavor called [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). I know very little about it, but from my understanding, its syntax allows 100% JavaScript but adds a superset of language features that you may appreciate *(lexical `this` being one)*. The resulting code compiles to 100% ECMAScript 3 code. May be something like what you want.

Comment: @juandopazo with all due respect, computer languages are not people, and following an important and fundamental principle, for the sake of good science, deserve critigue just like ideas do. Even bashing is perfectly fine. I did my fair share of ECMAScript-262 programming, a family of which JavaScript is part of, and I would have to agree that not all of it is equally suited for good programming or specific applications, of which OP has undoubtedly become aware of. That shouldn't deny him help. Falling in love with things clouds your judgement ;-)

Comment: @amn: The inverse of that thought would be that people are not computers. If you go to a JavaScript developer for help or advice, but proceed to defame that in which the developer specializes, that developer may decide to decline assistance. It's not about falling in love with things; it's about natural human response to off-putting behavior. I think juandopazo's comment is just good advice. Perhaps Jodes' "love" for Java has clouded his judgement in this instance. ;-)

Comment: *"and just about every feature JavaScript doesn't have."* - I personally think that it's exactly the other way round: In Javascript there's a lot more possible than in Java, since there is no compiler. This isn't always a good thing, because one can program in Javascript the same as in Java, but also the same as in C. There's a lot of JS code difficult to understand to Java programmers, so I agree with you that a Java-like compiler for JS would be a really great thing. But you can program your own framework anyway, since you can easily create objects with encapsulation in JS.

Comment: If you want to learn and work in JavaScript you have to forgot all Java for a while and start from scratch, understanding that "Java" in the name JavaScript hasn't anything to do with Java, it has no relationship behind the name (which was chosen for marketing reasons as Java was a popular language in mid nineties). After you know JavaScript on its own for a while, you can try to bring back concepts and/or patterns from Java, but respecting JavaScript itself and the available patterns on it and how they apply to it. That said, after you're ok with JS, you can try TypeScript as @IHateLazy said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use [ExtJS framework](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/). ExtJS provides MVC model to build UI.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Haxe](http://www.haxe.org), which is much like Java and may compile JavaScript code. By "compile" I mean that it takes your Haxe source code and translates it into a JavaScript program.

Answer (score 1):

Google Web Toolkit lets you write Java and compile to JavaScript. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/